# Add CSS to Pdfkit in Django?

Tags: python, django, pdf, pdfkit

I am not able to add my css to my PdfKit code.

The normal Static links in the HTML do not work.

```
<link href="{% static 'css/print.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

I see this approach in the View but can not find a way to link the css file in Django.

```
css = 'print.css'
pdfkit.from_file('file.html', css=css)
```

Also found this answer for Flask - how to do the same for Django?

[How to link stylesheet files to pdfkit in Flask application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914546/how-to-link-stylesheet-files-to-pdfkit-in-flask-application#40933139)

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add full path. Instead of

```
<link href="{% static 'css/print.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

you'd use

```
<link href="http://localhost/static/css/print.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The second approach you have found works too, but again you need to use full path for files, something like:

```
import os
from django.conf import settings

css = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'css', 'print.css')
pdfkit.from_file('file.html', css=css)
```

In the latter case you need to provide full path to `file.html` as well. In Django, however, you'd probably rather first render `file.html` to string and then use rendered html to create PDF. Something like:

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

t = render_to_string('file.html', {})
css = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'css', 'print.css')

pdf = pdfkit.from_string(t, 'file.pdf', css=css)
```

... or if you'd like to return PDF as response

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

pdf = pdfkit.from_string(t, False, css=css)
response = HttpResponse(pdf)
response['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename = file.pdf'
return response
```

Comment: should that be os.path.join?  this really helps and is what I was looking for!, thank you. using the static_root does require running the collectstatic  command whenever changes are made?

Comment: Yes, `os.path.join()`. Sorry, I mistyped that. And yes, using static_root generally means that you have to run collectstatic command every time you change static files.

Comment: I am cheating while in development.  I created a link directly to the css files.  css = os.path.join ( settings.CSS_ROOT, 'print.css' ).  For the CSS_ROOT I do CSS_ROOT = str ( APPS_DIR ( 'static/css' ) ). cool?

Comment: That's alright, if this makes development easier to you. I for example setup my development environment the same way as production to avoid possible deployment headache. It's a bit more work during development, but I prefer hassle-free deployment over hassle-free development :)